# custom rnn migration to tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2.x

I need to migrate the below part in my custom RNN implementation in tensorflow 1.x to tensorflow 2.x.

I am kind of stuck at the place where I need to convert tf.get_variable with initializers such as xaver initializers inside a tf.variable_scope.

I have referred the migration guide, but still I could not understand the conversion of tf.get_variable with xavier initialization, also I have to migrate few placeholders without a pre-defined shape.

```
        with tf.variable_scope(self._scope):

            with tf.variable_scope("PresentState"):
                self._U = tf.get_variable("U", shape=[self._num_in, self._n_hidden], dtype=tf.float32,
                                             initializer=xavier_initializer())
                self._W = tf.get_variable("W", shape=[self._n_hidden, self._n_hidden],
                                             dtype=tf.float32,
                                             initializer=xavier_initializer())
                self._b = tf.get_variable("B", shape=[self._n_hidden], dtype=tf.float32,
                                            initializer=xavier_initializer())
                self._p = None
```

Placeholder part.

```
p = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size, None, num_in], name="p")
```

Answer (score 0):

In idiomatic TF2.x code, you should not use tf.Placeholders, but instead define them as functions arguments to your callable `@tf.function`.  Since TF2.x now supports eager execution, you don't need any `tf.Session` calls and hence can pass your plain python variables to any `@tf.function`.

For the first part of your question:

I am not that deep into RNNs, but from your code it looks like you could refactor the inner `tf.variable_scope` into a [`tf.Module`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Module), which allows you to use xavier initialzation as follows (Not tested):

```
class PresentState(tf.Module):
  def __init__(self, ins, hiddens, outs):
    initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotNormal() # Xavier initialization
    self._U = tf.Variable(initializer([ins, outs]), dtype=tf.float32)
    self._W = tf.Variable(initializer([ins, outs]), dtype=tf.float32)
    self._b = tf.Variable(initializer([outs]), dtype=tf.float32)
    self._p = None
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to create a tf.module for the complete Rnn class, please find the Rnn implementation using tf1.x and possible tf.module implementation.

Comment: tf 1.x : https://gist.github.com/np000/a9123dcc64fdf1f4f13b1c1e56ee4e6e , tf 2.x https://gist.github.com/np000/92d79cb1e73ea06a55e0db355da5437a